# Why is 'end' still added to the list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

If the user types in 'end', it is supposed to print the list and 'end' should not be added to the list because of `while name != "end":`, however it is.

```
name = "";

names = []
while name != "end":
    name = input("Please enter a name")
    names.append(name)
    print("hi")

print(names)
```

If I type in Bob, Jim, end, the list should be `['Bob', 'Jim']`, but it is instead `['Bob', 'Jim', 'end']`

Comment: because you're appending _then_ you're testing...

Answer (score 5):

of course since you're appending right after having inputted the name

Prefer an infinite loop with a test in the middle (doing so saves a double test/a double `input` call):

```
while True:
    name = input("Please enter a name")
    if name == "end":
      break
    names.append(name)
```

For one-liners addicts, you can `itertools.takewhile` and `itertools.repeat`, but that's more difficult to comprehend when you're not used to, interesting though:

```
import itertools

names = list(itertools.takewhile(lambda x : x != "end",(input("Please enter a name") for _ in itertools.repeat(None))))
```

or even better & simpler thanks to comments:

```
names = list(iter(lambda:input("Please enter a name"), 'end'))
```

Comment: well... it's true that way you just write once the input, it's a nice answer... I fall in a rush and made mistakes haha, should think a little

Comment: that's a classic: I _never_ use conditions in `while` because you end up copying/pasting the same condition or call twice. Check my oneliner if you have aspirin handy :)

Comment: Nice inline one, in all the programming world, functional programming is my favorite. And Yes, it's a nice trick, I don't like so much about the infinite loops, not because of the infinite loops... all kind of "jump code", in your  case, you are breaking the code having a good conscience about what you are doing, but, the code could come unreadable if somebody use jumpers just because they are there and exist. That's why I regretted, I don't like it so much, I don't teach them a lot, but... it's true that a tool used well, is a good tool.

Comment: the trap is to turn the generator comprehension into a list comprehension. Then you never exit from the inner comp even if you enter "end". Sometimes, a simple loop is more understandable for everyone, yes. Functional programming should apply to finite inputs :)

Comment: That's tooooo clever ;)

Comment: Or you could use `iter` with a callable and a sentinel value: `names = list(iter(lambda:input("Please enter a name"), u'end'))`

Answer (score 1):

You have to ask before  enter the while and also inside it :), if you do it, you have to chance the order a little bit.

here `name = "";` you start with an empty string, and that's `"" != "end"`, so the first check is useless because then you ask for another input inside the loop, and that input could be "end", and will be appendended no matter what

```
name = input("Please enter a name")

names = []
while name != "end":
    print("hi")
    names.append(name)
    name = input("Please enter a name")


print(names)
```